# Are two strings anagrams or not?

Tags: haskell

I want to find if two strings are anagrams or not.. 
I thought to sort them,and then check one by one but is there any algorithms for sorting stings? or another idea to make it? (simple ideas or code because i am a beginner )thanks

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. The question is a bit short, but unlike many other requests for help at least this shows some effort, having reduced the problem to string sorting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are lists of characters in Haskell, so the standard `sort` simply works.

```
> import Data.List
> sort "hello"
"ehllo"
```

Your idea of sorting and then comparing sounds fine for checking anagrams.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you and idea-(as I am not that much acquainted with haskell).
Take an array having 26 spaces.

Now for each character in the first string you increase certaing position in array.

If array `A[26]={0,0,...0}`
Now if you find 'a' then put `A[1]=A[1]+1`;
    if 'b' then `A[2]=A[2]+1`;

Now in case of 2nd string for each character you decrease the values for each character found in the same array.(if you find 'a' decrease A[1] like `A[1]=A[1]-1`)

At last check if all the array elements are 0 or not. If 0 then definitely they are anagram else not an anagram.

Note: You may extend this for Capital letters similarly.

Comment: You can use a sparse array (the simplest version in Haskell would be an `IntMap`) to cover the full Unicode character set. For very long strings, this approach should work better than sorting. One variation is to walk both strings side by side, recording the *difference* between how many times each character has been seen in one string vs. the other. This makes the array sparser when the strings are similar, which may reduce the memory residency.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to count the crowd each letter.

Simply, you can sort your string and then check each element of two lists.

For example, you have this

```
"cinema" and "maneci"
```

It would be helpful to make your string into a list of characters.

```
['c','i','n','e','m','a'] and ['m','a','n','e','c','i']
```

Then , you can sort these list and you will check each character. 
Note that you will have these cases :

```
example [] [] = True
example [] a = False
example a [] = False 
example (h1:t1)(h2:t2) = if h1==h2 then _retroactively_ else False
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Joy of Haskell "Finding Success and Failure", pp.11-14, the authors offer the following code which works:

```
import Data.List

isAnagram :: String -> String -> Bool

isAnagram word1 word2 = (sort word1) == (sort word2)
```

After importing your module (I imported `practice.hs` into `Clash`), you can enter two strings which, if they are anagrams, will return true:

```
*Practice> isAnagram "julie" "eiluj"
True
```